# Do deleted answers eventually get removed permanently?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

I'm new to the whole '10k rep' level, so bear with me.

I can now see deleted answers on questions, which isn't a problem - but some of them seem to have stuck around for a long time, even long after the user that made them has been removed.

For example, [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124756/28182) (10k link only) from 2013:

[image: screenshot of a deleted answer from July 2013]

Are they eventually removed entirely, or do they stick around in perpetuity?

Comment: You can use the [Stack Exchange - Deleted Answer Manager](http://stackapps.com/q/3408/10706) user script / extension to automatically hide deleted answers. It can also be toggled to hide or show deleted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They stick around forever I'm afraid! Most of the time you shouldn't be too distracted by them since they're always displayed below other posts.

Comment: Pretty much the only exception is posts from users younger than 13

Comment: @badp do they get removed completely?

Comment: @shanodin They get removed immediately, completely, along with any trace of the user's existence. They are truly nuked from orbit.

Comment: So if a twelve year old posts the most brilliant answer ever, but admits that he is twelve, it'll be nuked?

Comment: @arperum Yes, them's the rules.

Comment: Does that actually happen?

Comment: @TZHX From time to time, yes.